Linear Gradients for box shadows
Im trying to use the code below to create a box shadow that has a linear gradient mainly to cover up a the edge line of a photo above the div listed below. Obviously this is not working and Im having a hard time finding a solution. It gives me a solid color all the way across and no gradient. Does anyone know how to properly do this?


.underimgborder {
  border: 0px solid #00ff89;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.048), rgb(0, 255, 136), rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.085))1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 40px #00ff89;
  position: relative;
}
<div class="underimgborder"></div>



I've tried finding solutions on youtube and google but nothing I've come across is helping.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see this guide on markdown formatting to better format questions going forward: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Also, you'll notice the code you provided is a gradient and not a solid color.

It may look like it is, but it is not. I dont need the border to be a gradient. I need the shadow to be a gradient. The border size is set to 0px because all I want is a shade essentially. If you pug the code into your editor and look at it, youll see what Im try to say. Id like the shadow to be the gradient. Not the border.

mainly to cover up a the edge line of a photo — why not just clip/crop the photo, either in a photo editor, or with CSS?

You can use a pseudo-element like ::before or ::after to create the gradient background and achieve the desired effect. You can change the shadow values as you like.


.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}
.basic {
  box-shadow: 10px 8px 10px 5px orange;
}
.shadow:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  inset: -5px;
  transform: translate(10px,8px);
  z-index: -1;
  background: conic-gradient(from 90deg at 40% -25%, #ffd700, #f79d03, #ee6907, #e6390a, #de0d0d, #d61039, #cf1261, #c71585, #cf1761, #d61039, #de0d0d, #ee6907, #f79d03, #ffd700, #ffd700, #ffd700);
  filter: blur(10px);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 30px;
}
<div class="box shadow"></div>
<div class="box basic"></div>



